# using shared pointers for loading into a variable c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Is this a reasonable thing to do?

```
void MyFunc(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>* p) {
  // calculate a, b, c
  p->reset(new MyClass(a, b, c));
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;
  MyFunc(&ptr);
  // do some other work with ptr
  return 0;
}
```

I read that it is not recommended to use raw pointers, only smart pointers, but in my function argument basically I'm using a raw pointer. Is this a bad practice

Comment: You could pass the smart pointer by reference instead of pointer.

Comment: Do you even need a pointer type here?  Can you pass `MyClass` by reference instead?

Comment: well, I'm trying to stick to a style where if a function argument is changed, then use pointers

Comment: @hovo That's what reference are for. The only situation where a pointer makes sense is if the parameter value could be null. If it doesn't make sense, a reference should by pass. If it's not modified, a const reference.

Comment: @Rosme Google's C++ style guide specifies that output arguments should be pointers https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments

Comment: @hovo dont believe everything that google tells you

Comment: @hovo This is really a question of taste. There are things in the Google C++ Style Guide that I really don't agree with, and this is one of them. Personnally, I prefer to see a reference in a signature, that way I automatically knows that I cannot pass a null object(nullptr). Where has if I see a pointer, while not being optional, I can pass it a null value without a risk of breaking everything. Their con reasoning on this is bogus to me.

Comment: @Rosme Clearly, Google C++ Style Guide has yet to meet Java ;)

Comment: I'm not sure the question is whether @hovo should follow the Google C++ Style Guide. But somehow, if you want to stick to the principle of having only pointer for output arguments, I see only two solutions: raw pointers (limited to the use of ouput parameters) or std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>. I kinda doubt that the second approach is sensible or even practical.

Comment: We follow this guideline where I work. The benefit is that it's more clear to the caller that the variable is being modified since you need to take the address. e.g. `foo(a, b)` vs `foo(a, &b)`. Obviously naming conventions are effective but they can only go so far if you have more than 1 or 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

More proper way would be:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyFunc()
{
  // calculate a, b, c
  return std::make_shared<MyClass>(a, b, c);
}
```

this is more readable and produce shorter and cleaner code:

```
int main() 
{
  auto ptr = MyFunc();
  // do some other work with ptr
  return 0;
}
```

It should be clear if possible for a reader what the function intention is just looking to it's name, parameters and return type. In your case there are way too many questions:

```
- why do I need to pass `std::shared_ptr` to the function?
- what will happen when that ptr is equal to `nullptr`?
- will this function use object passed in `std::shared_ptr` if it points to one?
```

None of that question exists when it returns `std::shared_ptr`. "Function creates object inside and returns shared ownership" - this is clear for every C++ programmer who would just look into function signature.

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely ever a good reason to pass a smart pointer by pointer. Pass it by reference instead:

```
void MyFunc(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>& p)
{
    // calculate a, b, c
    p.reset(new MyClass(a, b, c));
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;
    MyFunc(ptr);
    // do some other work with ptr
    return 0;
}
```

Or, in this example, just change the function to pass it in the return value instead of an output parameter:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyFunc()
{
    // calculate a, b, c
    return std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(a, b, c));
    // or:
    // return std::make_shared<MyClass>(a, b, c);
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr = MyFunc();
    // do some other work with ptr
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose two things:

1. You want to follow the Google C++ Style Guide recommendation stating that output arguments should be pointers,
2. *p* is an output argument or an input/output argument and cannot be made the return of the function.

I would say that it makes sense.

It is recommanded to prefer smart pointer to raw pointers to make ownership clearer and less prone to errors. But here, you are using the raw pointer in place of references, and references are not a problem. Thus, it seems reasonable to me, especially as the use of raw pointers would be limited to the case of "hand made" references.